# How to define several include path in Makefile

Tags: c++, include, makefile

New to C++; Basic understanding of includes, libraries and the compile process. Did a few simple makefiles yet.

My current project involves using an informix DB api and i need to include header files in more than one nonstandard dirs. How to write that ? Havent found anything on the net, probably because i did not use good search terms

This is one way what i tried (not working). Just to show the makefile

```
LIB=-L/usr/informix/lib/c++
INC=-I/usr/informix/incl/c++ /opt/informix/incl/public

default:    main

main:   test.cpp
        gcc -Wall $(LIB) $(INC) -c test.cpp
        #gcc -Wall $(LIB) $(INC) -I/opt/informix/incl/public -c test.cpp

clean:
        rm -r test.o make.out
```

Answer (score 136, accepted):

You have to prepend every directory with `-I`:

```
INC=-I/usr/informix/incl/c++ -I/opt/informix/incl/public
```

Comment: It still doesn't work for me, though running gcc manually does it.

Comment: @NoBugs I have the same issue. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 108):

You need to use `-I` with each directory. But you can still delimit the directories with whitespace if you use (GNU) make's `foreach`:

```
INC=$(DIR1) $(DIR2) ...
INC_PARAMS=$(foreach d, $(INC), -I$d)
```

Comment: Or shorter: `INC_PARAMS=$(INC:%=-I%)` with [substitutions](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Substitution-Refs.html). `$(foreach,,)` is more readable, but substitutions are so commonly used that it's good to familiarize how they work anyway.

Comment: or `INC_PARAMS = $(addprefix -I,$(INC))`.

Answer (score 4):

Make's [substitutions](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Substitution-Refs.html) feature is nice and helped me to write

```
%.i: src/%.c $(INCLUDE)
        gcc -E $(CPPFLAGS) $(INCLUDE:%=-I %) $< > $@
```

You might find this useful, because it asks `make` to check for changes in include folders too