# How do I include a path to boost when I use make?

Tags: c++, boost

I'm trying to install DSSP, which requires the boost libraries. I'm trying to specify the location of the boost libraries (/home/devin/boost_1_57_0), but make doesn't seem to recognize it.

I've tried:

```
make -I /home/devin/boost_1_57_0
make -I /home/devin/boost_1_57_0/boost
make -I ../boost_1_57_0
make -I/home/devin/boost_1_57_0
```

etc etc

I don't know why this isn't working.

I tried doing

```
CXXFLAGS="-I/home/devin/boost_1_57_0" make
```

But I still get errors:

```
In file included from src/mkdssp.cpp:8:
src/mas.h:27:29: error: boost/version.hpp: No such file or directory
src/mas.h:28:29: error: boost/cstdint.hpp: No such file or directory
src/mkdssp.cpp:17:37: error: boost/program_options.hpp: No such file or directory
src/mkdssp.cpp:18:48: error: boost/iostreams/filtering_stream.hpp: No such file or directory
```

Comment: make has no concept of c++ include paths. You need to tell make to pass this command-line flag on to the c++ compiler. The normal way to do that is: `CXXFLAGS="-I/home/devin/boost_1_57_0" make` or similar

Comment: Thanks, but I still get the same errors. Noted in edit.

Comment: where did you get the library from? There is usually a `./configure` or `./bootstrap` phase which finds all your libraries and sets their paths in the makefile.

Comment: Does this works? 
"g++ -I /home/devin/boost_1_57_0 your_main.cpp"
As Richard explained, -I option should be passed to g++, not make.

Comment: What's your_main.cpp ?

Comment: The name of the file you are compiling that contains your main function

Comment: If you want to add the include path in your makefile have a look there : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4134764/how-to-define-several-include-path-in-makefile

Comment: There are a few different .cpp files. When I don't include that part, it says there are no such files or directories.