# Installing tortonnel - missing 'boost/shared_ptr.hpp'

Tags: macos, boost, terminal, tor

Trying to install Tortunnel, i have downloaded ;

http://www.thoughtcrime.org/software/tortunnel/tortunnel-0.3.tar.gz

extracted the file changed the directory am in to the extracted folder with terminal

```
 cd tortunnel-0.3
```

and applied the

```
 ./configure
```

got to the step where i have to

```
make && make install
```

and then i got ;

```
 ./TorProxy.h:33:10: fatal error: 'boost/shared_ptr.hpp' file not found
 #include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
     ^
 1 error generated.
 make: *** [TorProxy.o] Error 1
```

i made sure to install boost, and since i got brew on my mac it was simple;

```
 brew install boost
```

without changing the the directory am in, i assumed it wont effect the boost installation.

then i ran the command;

```
 make && make install
```

got the same error.

going over the files i made sure shared_ptr.hpp is present, and the file location is;

```
/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.60.0_2/include/boost
```

the tortunnel-0.3 file location is ;

```
 /Users/PK/Downloads
```

so is this error i am getting because the files locations as i assume ?, and how could i fix this ?

Comment: Did you set `/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.60.0_2/include` as your include path in make file ?

Comment: i guess not since i am not sure how to do this ? i would appreciate an elaboration on how to do this ?

Comment: I am not sure how your make file looks like. But you can look for something like `INC` or `CXXINC` and append the path I mentioned before to that make variable. If not present you can introduce one and add that to the compilation command.  Provided link might be helpful : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4134764/how-to-define-several-include-path-in-makefile

Comment: This is a duplicate of your earlier post, I posted an answer there on how to specify include path.