# How to run a makefile that takes in all header files within a subdirectory

Tags: c++, makefile

I'm extremely confused over how to make in c++. I'm working on a school project where we downloaded several files -- some starter code, and some libraries. File structure is something along the lines of

```
main --- lib/ severalLibraryFolders
    \--- src/ starterCode
```

I cannot seem to get the starter code to make within the command line. There's a vector library within one of the library folders and when I run make on the starter file (a .cpp and .h) I get a `fatal error: 'vector.h' not found`. I managed to use gcc and the `-I` flag to include the folder that vector.h was in which fixed it -- however other similar problems popped up even after I used the `-I` flag on all possible library folders.

I'm fairly certain I'm doing something wrong/need a makefile but all the examples I've found are not clear on how to do what I need to do, which is essentially to find all header files below the parent directory. I'd love some direction here, as I come from a more scripty background where this sort of thing is much easier!

Comment: What error message are you getting with your current setup?

Comment: I think you can check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4134764/how-to-define-several-include-path-in-makefile

Comment: Hey Sam -- My current error is `fatal error: 'private/init.h' file not found`. I have the `private` folder included with a -I, and init.h is inside of it. I'm confused over why this isn't working.

Comment: Try using `-I` to include the directory that *contains* `private/`. (And when you write your own code, remember: hard-coded header paths are a pain.)