# Makefile doesn't find .hpp

Tags: c++, gcc, makefile

I have 2 directories in my project, one called Builds, who has the Makefile and a test program ( test-P0-consola.cpp ) and other one directory called P0 who constains the classes I use, cadena (string) and fecha (date).

test-P0-consola.cpp includes both of them, but Make doesn't find them.

```
CPP = g++
CPPFLAGS = -std=c++14 -g -Wall -pedantic

VPATH = ../P0:.:..

test-consola: test-P0-consola.o fecha.o cadena.o
    ${CPP} ${CPPFLAGS} -o $@.ex $^

test-P0-consola.o: test-P0-consola.cpp fecha.hpp cadena.hpp
    ${CPP} -c ${CPPFLAGS} $< -o $@

fecha.o: fecha.hpp
cadena.o: cadena.hpp
```

It throws the fatal error "cadena.hpp doesn't exist the file or directory" when it tries to compile test-P0-consola.o, but It find them out when I force it to compile cadena or fecha. I'm using GCC and Ubuntu.

```
..
├── Builds
│   ├── makefile.mak
│   └── test-P0-consola.cpp
├── P0
│   ├── cadena.cpp
│   ├── cadena.hpp
│   ├── fecha.cpp
│   └── fecha.hpp
```

**EDIT**

Error:

```
g++ -std=c++14 -g -Wall -pedantic -c test-P0-consola.cpp
test-P0-consola.cpp:7:21: fatal error: fecha.hpp: There is no file or directory

compilation terminated.

makefile.mak:9: Failure in the instructions for the objective 'test-P0-consola.o'

make: *** [test-P0-consola.o] Error 1
```

Comment: Can you describe the specific error and specific build you are doing, and print the full directory tree at the start of the build? It's unclear what the error is.

Comment: I added the full error as well as the directory tree. I'm just trying to execute a test that checks if the classes have some error. It works fine if you compile them in the same folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put in the makefile the include path of the .hpp files you need the compiler to use. You should use the `-Ipath` compiler directive, where path is the path of your include files.

See `[Makefile: How to correctly include header file and its directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22545029/makefile-how-to-correctly-include-header-file-and-its-directory)

and

[How to define several include path in Makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4134764/how-to-define-several-include-path-in-makefile)

Something like:

```
CPP = g++
CPPFLAGS = -std=c++14 -g -Wall -pedantic
INC = -Iyourincludebasepath/P0

VPATH = ../P0:.:..

test-consola: test-P0-consola.o fecha.o cadena.o
    ${CPP} ${CPPFLAGS} ${INC} -o $@.ex $^

test-P0-consola.o: test-P0-consola.cpp fecha.hpp cadena.hpp
    ${CPP} -c ${CPPFLAGS} ${INC} $< -o $@

fecha.o: fecha.hpp
cadena.o: cadena.hpp
```

Comment: I thought you didn't have to add -I, thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

Look closely at your error:

```
test-P0-consola.cpp:7:21: fatal error: fecha.hpp: There is no file or directory
```

You probably have something like:

```
// test-P0-consola.cpp
#include "fetcha.hpp"
```

But `fetcha.hpp` is not in that directory, so it can't find it. You either need to change the way you include the file directly (via `#include "../P0/fetcha.hpp"`) or to change the build rule to pass in an additional include path (via `-I../P0`).

---

Note: I'm not sure there's a reason to add `.` to `VPATH`. That's kind of implicit.

Note 2: this is a bad idea:

```
test-consola: test-P0-consola.o fecha.o cadena.o
    ${CPP} ${CPPFLAGS} -o $@.ex $^
                          ~~~~~
```

Don't lie to Make. The result of running a recipe should be the target file, except for PHONY targets. The recipe here should be `-o $@`. If you want the `.ex` suffix, you should change the target to be `test-consola.ex`. If you still want the rule to be named `test-consola`, you'll want:

```
test-consola : test-consola.ex
test-consola : .PHONY
```

Comment: The problem was I didn't added -I, I take note about your notes! Thank you